# Pass a URL Field into the src of an iFrame in a visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, iframe

Here is a basic code of what I am trying to do:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:iframe src="CannotFigureOut" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

If I simply hard code in a URL in place of CannotFigureOut the iFrame works the way I want it to.  However, I want to reference a URL Field I have on the Page/Custom Object I am in.

I have a custom object where a user can input a unique URL when they create it and/or whenever they want.  I want the iFrame/VisualForce Page to show the URL from that field.

I am sure the answer is simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a standard controller to get access to the URL field. Next, you just need to reference it like a normal expression. Here's your example, modified:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:iframe src="{!Account.Website}" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Replace "Account" and "Website" with the appropriate object and field name.